# Não sei como pegar a latitude e longitude usando GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app em android usando Kotlin, segui um tutorial de um tópico daqui, porém ele pegava a ultima localização que foi salva, não latitude e longitude, que é o que eu necessito. Segue o código:

```
class InserirAbastecimentoActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

lateinit var googleApiClient:GoogleApiClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inserir_abastecimento)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build()

    //Conectar com GoogleApi
    googleApiClient.connect()
...}
    override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    pararConexaoComGoogleApi()
}

fun pararConexaoComGoogleApi(){
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected){
        googleApiClient.disconnect()
    }
}

override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("Tag", "Conexão bem sucedida")
}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {
}

override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    pararConexaoComGoogleApi()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Eu te recomendaria a utilizar FusedLocationProviderClient.

`fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)`

Você adiciona um listener nele que vai te devolver um objeto Location quando ele conseguir pegar a localização e dentro dele estão a latitude de logitude:

`fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
         var latitude= location.latitude.toString()
         var longitude= location.longitude.toString()
        }`

Fonte: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current